# php7.4 opcache.preload - Errors on fpm start

Tags: php, preload, opcache, php-7.4

I'm upgrading to php7.4 and want to take advantage of the new opcache preloading.

When I `service php7.4-fpm start` I get the following errors:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: Failed opening required '/mnt/a/b/c/opcachePreload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/mnt/a/b/c:/mnt/a/b/d') in Unknown on line 0
php7.4-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=70/n/a
Failed to start The PHP 7.4 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

My `fpm/php.ini` includes the following opcache settings:

```
include_path              = ".:/usr/share/php:/mnt/a/b/c"

opcache.save_comments           = 1
opcache.max_accelerated_files   = 7963
opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16
opcache.fast_shutdown           = 1
opcache.revalidate_freq         = 0

opcache.validate_timestamps     = 0
opcache.memory_consumption      = 128
opcache.preload                 = /mnt/a/b/c/opcachePreload.php
opcache.preload_user            = www-data
```

I've tried having the `opcachePreload.php` contain only `<?php` and the error still happened, normally it contains something like this, with a couple of absolute paths in the array:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

$scriptsArr = [
    'path',
    'path',
];
foreach ($scriptsArr as $fileStr) {
    opcache_compile_file($fileStr);
}
```

I've tried a range of different levels of file-permissions on it (0600, 0700, 0770, 0777, owned by root), currently `ls -l /mnt/a/b/c/opcachePreload.php` shows:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 336 Dec 26 15:11 /mnt/a/b/c/opcachePreload.php
```

Is it a file-permission problem, or a conflict in the configurations, or a php7.4 bug, or something else?

Is the `opcache.preload` interpreted as some sort of relative path instead of absolute? (I've tried `opcache.preload = ./opcachePreload.php`)

What else can I try?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, did you check the permissions on `/mnt/a/b/c/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put your `opcachePreload.php` inside for example `/var/www/html` and change `opcache.preload` to

```
opcache.preload = /var/www/html/opcachePreload.php
```

If that works then `www-data` doesn't have permission to access files in `/mnt/a/b/c/`